# Titles in css menu change width while hovering

Tags: css, menu, width, title

I am implementing a very simple css menu. However, if I select a menu title in the menu bar (and thus open the menu associated with it) the width of the title extends to the width of the menu, which is not desired (i.e. the width of the title should not change). Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yogibimbi/8U5An/3/), or have a look at the markup:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript: showLogin()">you</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript: showLogin()">register...</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: showLogin()">login...</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: showLogin()">forgot password...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li><a href="javascript: selectMenu()">qan</a></li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li style="width: 20px"><a class="site">be</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript: false">be</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: false">do</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the css definitions:

```
#menu {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: darkgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 3;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
#menu>ul>li {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 1px 0px 1px;
  width: auto;
  /*width: 10px;*/
}
#menu a { color: inherit; text-decoration: none;}
#menu>ul>li>a:hover { background-color: grey;}
#menu>ul ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  line-height: 14px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
#menu>ul ul>li {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 5px;
  margin: 0px -3px;
}
#menu>ul ul>li:hover { color: lightgrey; background-color: grey;}
#menu>ul>li:hover ul { display: block;}
```

Since the menus are generated dynamically and contents meant to change on the fly and the font used is proportional, I cannot just set the widths of a title to a constant value which suppresses the resize. The width of the title should be determinded solely by the width of the text.
It used to work when I had implemented yuimenus, but that did all kinds of stuff to my CSS, the ramifications of which I found hard to control, so now I cooked up the menu by myself and am quite happy with it, save for the width change, and I haven't figured out which part of yui suppressed that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with max-width.. this will make the link's width content-independent
use `position:absolute;` for the submenu: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqcQq/)

Comment: YES, YES, and more YESses! I knew I was missing something little. That did exactly the trick! Thanks a lot! Now, how can I upvote your answer 10-fold? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Set width in `li`

Your updated example :- http://jsfiddle.net/8U5An/8/

Css:-

```
   #menu ul li {
       width: 25px;
   }
```

See some useful example as well , how they handle same case by using `width` only :-

http://www.diy.com/diy/jsp/index.jsp?noCookies=false

http://www.puregrips.com/

Comment: ummm, yes, but I said in my original post already that I need to change the texts for the titles dynamically and that I therefore cannot use a set width anywhere near the titles. In addition, I could have mentioned that I wanted the texts to stay contiguous, but I reckoned that followed logically from what I had said before so, thanks for answering, but no cookie this time;-) Omer Yotam's solution is right on the money, though.